# Call parent view controller method from WEPopoverController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I'm using an iOS popover implementation from here:
https://github.com/PaulSolt/WEPopover

What's the best way for me to call a parent view controller method from within the WEPopoverController?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Delegates.
2. NotificationCenter.

These are the two Best ways to send message to object of other class.